# iOS "widget" style interface

Tags: ios, user-interface, widget

I am trying to come up with a good way to design an app with a "plug-in" or "widget" style interface (where plug-ins are simply `UIViews` for example, that can be added as a subview on a `UIScrollView`). Essentially, something like the iOS Notification Center where I can have lets say 3 "widgets" all of different heights but they fit perfectly based on the previous "widgets" height, maybe even be able to re-order widgets. Where is a good place to start?

```
----------------
|  ----------  | <- UIScrollView
|  | widget |  |
|  |   1    |  |
|  ----------  |
|  ----------  |
|  | widget | <- UIViews
|  |  ...   |  |
|  |   2    |  |
|  ----------  |
|  ----------  |
|  | widget <- UILabel (for example)
|  |   3    |  |
|  ----------  |
----------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like making it a UITableViewController and having each widget be a UITableViewCell would be a good idea. This would make editing and rearranging simple and easy